# Python truncates strings after 32 characters?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

So I wrote the following straightforward Python script that takes in data from a CSV and outputs these config files for a 3D printer. Everything is working great except when I add strings together in the double for loop it cuts off the string after 32 characters. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to prevent it? Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np

file = open('QualityData.csv')

data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",",dtype=str) #importing data

headers=data[[0,1],:]
data = np.delete(data,(0,1),0) #delete rows

titles=data[:,0]
data = np.delete(data, 0,1) #delete columns

r,c=np.shape(data)
profs = np.zeros((r,c))
profs = np.array(profs,dtype=str) #build data array for config file


for i in range(r):  #fill data array
    for j in range(c):
        if i in (0,4,5,12,13):
            profs[i,j]=titles[i]
        else:
            profs[i,j]=titles[i]+' = '+data[i,j]
            print(profs[i,j])

for k in range(c): #create filename and save it
    varient=str(data[11,k])
    varient=varient.replace(' ','_')
    filename = str(data[10,k]) + '_' + varient + '_' + str(data[8,k])+'.inst.cfg'
    np.savetxt(filename, profs[:,k], newline='\n',fmt='%s')
```

There are strings longer than 32 characters that get put into the titles array without a problem, but when they're added together in the else statement it only accepts the first 32 characters.

Comment: Why are you using NumPy for this? NumPy string dtypes are fixed-length.

Comment: It seemed like the easiest way with my fairly limited python skill set to manipulate the data using arrays. If there's a better way you can point me to I'm happy to rewrite my code.

Comment: The [stdlib `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and ordinary list/tuple manipulation.

Comment: I bet you can just set the string dtype size somehow.

Comment: you're correct, but as soon as I change it python treats them as bytes and not strings, so either there's incompatibility when I concatenate later or the save text encloses every line in b' '

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry yesterday. If you replace `dtype=str` with `dtype='|S100'` everywhere, you should be able to store strings up to 100 characters long. You can put any number in there.